# I have a nestjs and typeorm application in kubernetes. This application of mine connects in a mysql docker container with the host: 127.0.0.1

Tags: kubernetes, nestjs, typeorm

I have a nestjs and typeorm application in kubernetes. This application of mine connects in a mysql docker container with the host: **127.0.0.1**. In a remote access without kubernetes it works normally but in kubenetes:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16)
[Nest] 1 - 07/18/2022, 1:24:05 AM [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (6
)... +3007ms
```

Does anyone know any solutions to make **127.0.0.1** work within kubernetes? remembering if I use the computer's ipv4 it works normally but I wanted to do it through the host **127.0.0.1**

Answer (score 0):

`127.0.0.1` wont work inside K8s. Are you managing `mysql` yourself or using a managed service ? In either if the case the base url will have to be replaced with a kubernetes resolvable service name.
Check this out for more info

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/

If everything on the infra is already set, all you have to is refer mysql using `ENVIRONMENT` variable and update it accordingly during the deployment